# Kubuntu 18.0.4 How to install KDE Plasma version 5.17 and remove 5.12.9

Tags: kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYn4UYQ-nTo) on YouTube to customize my KDE. he is using KDE 5.17 I guess. I just installed kubuntu when I started the customization it doesn't looks the same. maybe because he using KDE 5.17. any suggestions how to get KDE 5.17? my Kubuntu have KDE 5.12.9 now. thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubuntu 18.04 will remain on KDE Plasma 5.12.x. You will only get updates to 5.12.x.

If you want a higher version, an option is to use Kubuntu 19.10 which, unlike Kubuntu 18.04 LTS, is supported for only **nine** months from the date of its release in October 2019. The release notes are here: https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-19-10-is-released-today/.

Another option is to wait for the release of Kubuntu 20.04 LTS scheduled for the second half of April 2020 with three years of support. That will come with KDE Plasma 5.18.x.

Yet another option is to use [KDE neon](https://neon.kde.org/) but we don't support KDE neon here. Support for KDE neon is available at our related site [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forumdisplay.php/242-KDE-neon), [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), and [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/).